# Django: Should I separate the web pages into different apps?

Tags: django, project

I am developing a business directory website, and it has

- Home page
- Search Result page
- Listing page

I am currently at the design stage and someone suggested to separate the pages/functions into different apps, eg.

- home
- search_result
- listing

Is this the best practise in the Django community? Or what would you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. These sound like different views within a single business app.

You definitely don't want a new app per DetailView, ListView, or SearchView. That would quickly become confusing...

Think of what the app structure actually does: it adds database database table prefixes (appname_), splits `models.py` files and encourages its own views.py file and tests.py file.

The differences between the home, search_result, and listing **views** don't justify the above   in my opinion.

If you want a directory/file structure that separates your distinct views, you could build a `views` directory in your app which contains individual `search_result.py` views... if they are long.